# How to change the wording of front-end `next article` for custom type registered in a plug-in?

Tags: plugin-development, next-post-link

I am working with another developer on a plugin that register and defines a custom type of posts. It's working as intended in the back-end but I would like to change the wording of `next article` and `previous article` chunks in the front-end to something like `next figure`. It must be defined in the plugin, not in the theme.

How can I achieve that ?

edit:
In the end I wrote that, alongside the other filters:

```
add_filter('next_post_link', 'next_figure_link');
function next_figure_link($arg) {
  if (get_post_type() == 'ct_figure') {
    $arg = str_replace('Next Article', 'Next figure', $arg);}
  return $arg;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'previous_figure_link');
function previous_figure_link($arg) {
  if (get_post_type() == 'ct_figure') {
    $arg = str_replace('Previous article', 'Previous figure', $arg);}
  return $arg;
}
```

But I wish I had used the `$format` and `$link` argument of the function instead of a brutal `str_replace`. But can it be done ?

Comment: You should be able to tie into the next or previous item hooks however you built the plugin.

Comment: I added this in the plugin PHP file (along with some other hooks that work): `function next_figures_link() {next_posts_link('Next figure', 'Next figure (2nd argument'), TRUE);}` and `add_filter('next_posts_link', 'next_figures_link');`

But nothing is changed on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is coming from the Theme's language file, can you explain why the translating has to be done by the plugin? Language files are designed for this.

But, if you really want to do this, use the gettext filter:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext

Using this to much may impact preformance.
https://pippinsplugins.com/dangers-gettext-filter/

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: The plugin must be theme independent because it's going to be used on different wordpres installations that have their own themes set.

Can I distribute a generic Theme language file that I could bundle with the plugin and that would be picked up whatever the theme being used ?